# What is the difference between "baruch" and "mevorach" regarding G-d?

Tags: tefilla, words

There is a phrase said just prior to the *Shacharit* Amidah that says:

תהילות לאל עליון ברוך הוא ומבורך

What is the difference in meaning between ברוך and ומבורך. Don't both mean "blessed"?

I realize that there is similar language in *ברכו*. However, I understand that phrasing better as there, *ברכו* is a verb and b/c the word is המבורך with a definite article in front, it appears to turn that into a noun which means "the one that is (should be?) blessed.

The phrase that I cited doesn't seem to have quite the same meaning as *ברכו* from what I can tell.

Comment: I found a lot of interesting sources on sefaria, perhaps I’ll be able to form an answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rabinu Bachya in Kad HaKemach [Here](https://www.sefaria.org/Kad_HaKemach%2C_Blessing.1.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) writes that ברוך means the source of blessings, מקור הברכה - all blessing come from him.

While מבורך means he is blessed by all, מבורך בפי כל - all his creations recognize that blessing is received through him.

Comment: Thanks. I love succinct answers like this!